# Start the for loop again when the condition is false java

Tags: java, for-loop

```
for (int f = 0; f < getBlocks().size(); f++) {
    if (getBlocks().get(f).x > 0 && getBlocks().get(f).x < 360) {
        move2 = true;
        move = true;
    } else if (getBlocks().get(f).x < 360) {
        move2 = true;
        move = false;
    } else if (getBlocks().get(f).x > 0) {
        move2 = false;
        move = true;
    } else {
        move2 = false;
        move = false;
    }
}
```

I want this for loop to start over when the f is bigger than the blocks size.

Comment: You can check `if f => blocks size` and make `f = 0` inside of the loop. This don't help?

Comment: When this loop finishes f is exactly equal to  getBlocks().size() (assuming getBlocks().size() returns an integer) but it gets out of scope since it's declared inside the loop, so it vanishes. You must clarify what you need.

Answer (score 3):

To start a loop again when the condition is false, wrap the loop in another loop:

For example:

```
while (true) {
  for (int f = 0; f < getBlocks().size(); f++) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This just keeps on executing the for loop over and over.

---

Note that an enhanced for loop would be a lot cleaner than your for loop:

```
for (Block b : getBlocks()) {
  if (b.x > 0 && b.x < 360) {
    // ...
  } // Etc.
}
```